# Installing R "tvReg" package to HPC cluster

Tags: r, package, putty, hpc

I am trying to install some packages on my local folder. I just write

```
install.packages("tvReg" , repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
```

On top of my R script. The results seem like the package is being installed like other packages but when I want to use it

```
library(tvReg)
```

it shows an error telling that there is no such package.

I checked the `my-R-libs` folder, and there is no tvReg after installation. I also tried to copy the package files directly from GitHub link https://github.com/cran/tvReg, but this time the error says this is not a valid package and deletes it from the folder. All other packages I want to use are working correctly and this is the only one I can't install.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the installation did not finish successfully.
This package depends on a number of other packages.
Try to install it again and pay attention to the last lines. You should see the following lines:

```
** package 'tvReg' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (tvReg)
```

When installation is completed, test it:

```
library("tvReg")
# Loading required package: Matrix
# Funded by the Horizon 2020. Framework Programme of the European Union.
```

You can also execute the following command:`.libPaths()` . It will list directories where R will search for packages. Your user directory should be first on that list. This directory will be used by default when you install R packages.